# Power tower question

Tags: power-towers

$$x^{x^{x^{.^{.^{.}}}}} = 8$$

Then how to solve for x?

I first tried like this

$x^8=8$ but I don't get any way to solve.

Comment: I don't see why solving $x^8=8$ does not work. It has $2$ real solutions, namely $2^{3/8}$ and $-2^{3/8}$.

Comment: Well, you also have to show that $\large{x_{n+1} = x^{x_n}}$ converges.

Comment: @Levent do we need to take log?

Comment: Related: [How can I prove the convergence of a power-tower?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1089458/how-can-i-prove-the-convergence-of-a-power-tower) In summary the power-tower converges for all $x\in[1/e^e, e^{1/e}]$. $2^{3/8}$ is inside this interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to obtain an analytical solution in terms of elementary functions.

However, one can find an expression in terms of the [Lambert W function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html). This expression evaluates to $8=-\frac{W(-ln(x))}{ln(x)}$. This expression can be solved using numerical methods.

However, as noted by others you may notice that infinite [tetration](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration) (technical word for power-tower) of $x$ converges if and only if $x \in [e^{-e},e^{1/e}]$. Therefore, your may use your positive real solution to $x$ for $x^8=8$. This will be identical to the solution to your question since:
$$e^{-e}<x<e^{1/e}$$
Therefore, $x$ cannot converge to any other value.

Comment: Can you explain a bit in detail how you got that inequality?

Answer (score 2):

Notice that

$$x^8=8\\\implies x=\sqrt[8]8\approx1.29683955465$$

And since

$$e^{-e}<x<e^{e^{-1}}$$

then it converges to the proposed number.

It then remains that none of the other solutions to $x^8=8$ are possible, which is explained in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/814417/272831).

Comment: Can I know how you got that inequality?

Comment: Did you try reading the link in my answer?